# Overlapping "Zoom" div blocking text and options select

Tags: html, text, zooming, blocking, overlapping

First question on this page - yay!

I am currently building a website for a client and it is causing me some troubles.

I have a zoom-tool which allows the user to zoom an image, when the cursor is passing the picture.

This creates a "secret" div right on top of my text-div. The text-div contains a select-option dropdown. The "secret" div is blocking for any activity with in the text-div - I cannot highlight any text or select a option in the dropdown. This I am able to do, when I move the text-div away from the "secret" div.

See this page: http://shakermedia.dk/2up/2012/10/seville-modulsofa-sort/

What can I do? Here is the css code for the two divs:

```
    div.zoom-box {
    width:450px;
    line-height: 0;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.text-alignment {
    width:450px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-419px;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

How can I make the text-div accessible, but keeping the "zoom-box" the same place (overlapping text when zooming)?

Your help is very much appriciated!

Comment: Just show the div.zoom-box when making zoom, when not hide it so the underlying div can be operated, also you should post the full html and javascript to get more concrete answers.

Comment: How do I do that? "Just show the div.zoom-box when making zoom, when not hide it so the underlying div can be operated"

Comment: Try to setup a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net so we can reproduce your issue and suggest proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try giving the element that is behind a lower value of **z-index** and the element that is above - a higher **z-index** value